# iOs high memory usage

Tags: ios, memory-management, instruments

Now i 've got a project with ARC, which use over 6m memory on pushing chat ViweController(UItableview with custom cells). I have no idea about why it happening. The most interesting that i cant identify for what reason it needs too much memory. So this is my Instruments screenshot:

[image]

In more detail view it looks like:

[image]

I think libRip.A.dylib needs too much memory. Have you got any ideas about it?

And please explain me what is  and strange libRip.A.dylib library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507212/ripzonedataalloc) that libRIP call is responsible for drawing a UIViewController with a background image.

**EDIT:**

Apparently this problem happens when you're setting a view's `backgroundColor` using `[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:]`.

A way around it is to use a UIImageView as background instead. As described [here](http://www.cocoaintheshell.com/2011/01/colorwithpatternimage-memory-usage/).

Comment: May be you right, because i use [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background"]]]; for background image. Is there another way to have image as a background?

Comment: Nop, but what is the size of the image?

Comment: 640*960. What min size should i use?

Comment: If it is a repeating pattern just make it like 16x16. Is it?

Comment: Of course. I just try it - as the result absolutely the same situation. When i comment out this line - all works fine, memoru allocation around 1m, but with any image 3m and more. Maybe there is another method how to set background image ass normal image?

Comment: I found this solution: http://www.cocoaintheshell.com/2011/01/colorwithpatternimage-memory-usage/ Maybe it will be helpful!

Comment: Editing the answer to include that info.