# How to tile a UIImage vertically while only streching horizontally on iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios6, uiimageview, uiimage

I have an image that can be stretched in the horizontal direction, but need to be tiled vertically (one on top of the other) to fill my view. How could I do this?

I know that an image can be made resizable by using the `-(UIImage *)resizableImageWithCapInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)capInsets` method. So that works great for the horizontal direction but that method cannot be used for the vertical direction it really needs to be tiled, and not stretched in the vertical direction to work.

Now my idea of how this could work is to run a loop that creates a UIImageView with the horizontally stretched image, and simply adjust the frame.origin.y property, then add it as a subview each loop until I've gone past the height of the view. However this seems like an overly complex way of doing this and really not practical when the view need to be resized (on an iPad rotation for example)

Is there a simpler more efficient way of doing this on iOS 6.x?

Answer (score 4):

I used this to tile an image horizontally in a UIImageView:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"my_image"];
UIImage *tiledImage = [image resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeTile];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:tiledImage];
```

This assumes you set the frame of the UIImageView to a larger size than your image asset. If the height is taller than your image, it will also tile vertically.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [UIColor](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html)'s method `colorWithPatternImage:` to create a repeating pattern and just pass an image with the correct horizontal width?

Code Example:

```
 // On your desired View Controller

 - (void)viewDidLoad
 { 
      [super viewDidLoad];
      UIImage *patternImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"repeating_pattern"];
      self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:patternImage];

      // ... do your other stuff here...
 }
```

Comment: Yes I have, the problem with this method is that I would need an image for every view width I would be supporting. So in this case 320px for the iPhone, and then both horizontal and vertical widths for the iPad. Three may not sound like much but I want my code to be able to adapt to any situation. Basically I want to future proof it.

Comment: There is a tradeoff here. Setting backgroundColor like this will cause [a leak in your application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703396/ios-high-memory-usage). I'm not sure of a better alternative as of yet, so this is more just to make you aware.

Answer (score 1):

So I've figured out a solution for this. It is I think a little jacky but it works.

Basically what I've done was to create my stretchable image with the left and right caps specified. And then I initialize a UIImageView with it. I then adjust the frame of the image view to the desired width. This will appropriately resize the image that is contained within it.

Then finally I used a piece of code I found that creates a new image by vertically tiling the adjusted image that is now contained in the image view. Notice how instead of accessing the original UIImage I am using the UIImageView view's image property.

The last thing then is to set the new UIImage as the patterned background colour of the view

Here is the code:

```
// create a strechable image
        UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"progressBackgroundTop@2x.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 60, 0, 60)];

        // create the image view that will contain it
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        CGRect frame = imageView.frame;
        frame.size.width = self.view.bounds.size.width;
        imageView.frame = frame;

        // create the tiled image
        CGSize imageViewSize = imageView.bounds.size;
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageViewSize);
        CGContextRef imageContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextDrawTiledImage(imageContext, (CGRect){ CGPointZero, imageViewSize }, imageView.image.CGImage);
        UIImage *finishedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:finishedImage];
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `imageView.image.CGImage` should be the same as `image.CGImage`; the magic happens elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"];
UIImage *resizableImage = [image resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, image.size.width / 2, 0, image.size.width / 2)];
```

Comment: Not solution, because it stretched in the middle, and not repeat vertically